# Display SharePoint Content Type Columns

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to use an Excel VBA macro to gather data from my SharePoint content type columns and display it in an excel spreadsheet.

When using the CompanyID function it returns the correct result. However, when I try to return the Title of the file it just returns 0. Is there anything I need to add or change within my code to fix this issue?

```
Function CompanyID()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  For Each prop In wb.ContentTypeProperties
    If prop.Name = "CompanyID" Then
      CompanyID = prop.Value
    End If
  Next prop
End Function
```

```
Function Title()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  For Each prop In wb.ContentTypeProperties
    If prop.Name = "Title" Then
      Title = prop.Value
    End If
  Next prop
End Function
```

Here is the 2 cells that are populated. I have used =Title() to call the title function and =CompanyID() to call the CompanyID Function.

[image: Excel Sheet]

The expected outcome of the Name cell should be Testing instead of 0.

Comment: Inside your function you can add `Debug.Print prop.Name, prop.Value` and review the full list - does it contain "Title" ?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I managed to fix the issue using the answer I posted below. I think there was a conflict with using the Title property. Using the code I posted below I was able to retrieve the file property title and was still able to use the code I previously mentioned for other String related columns.

Answer (score 1):

I tested if the issue was a string related issue or an issue with using the "Title" property and when I created a separate column in my content type and entered a string this worked fine. So I decided to change my code specifically for getting the Title and used the following code which I found online after doing some research.

```
Function DocProp(Info_needed As String) As Variant
 Application.Volatile
 DocProp = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(Info_needed).Value
 End Function
```